# FieldInspector: an API for deep object comparison and null checking

Tags: java

Here's my `FieldInspector`. It compares objects by field values and performs deep null checking. What do you think? It works, but I'm not happy with how it looks. I don't believe it's an example of clean code. How can I improve it?

That "memorizing" was my solution to cyclic dependencies. Otherwise, you get `StackOverflowError` when jumping back and forth from one element in an object graph to another

```java
package by.afinny.credit.unit.testUtil;

import by.afinny.credit.testUtil.fieldInspector.BasicFieldInspector;
import by.afinny.credit.testUtil.fieldInspector.FieldInspector;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

class BasicFieldInspectorTest {
    private FieldInspector fieldInspector;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        fieldInspector = new BasicFieldInspector();
    }

    @Test
    void testIsFullyInitialized_withoutDeepInspection() {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.string = "test string";
        classA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
        classA.classB = new ClassB();

        assertThat(fieldInspector.isFullyInitialized(classA)).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void testIsFullyInitialized_withDeepInspection_withoutFullInitialization() {
        fieldInspector.setDeepInspectionCandidates(Set.of(ClassB.class));

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.string = "test string";
        classA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
        classA.classB = new ClassB();

        assertThat(fieldInspector.isFullyInitialized(classA)).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testIsFullyInitialized_withDeepInspection_withFullInitialization_cyclicDependenciesResolved() {
        fieldInspector.setDeepInspectionCandidates(Set.of(ClassB.class));

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.string = "classA test string";
        classA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;

        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        classB.string = "classB test string";
        classB.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.TEN;
        classB.classA = classA;

        classA.classB = classB;

        assertThat(fieldInspector.isFullyInitialized(classA)).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void testIsFullyInitialized_withDeepInspection_afterMethodInvocation_cacheInvalidated() {
        fieldInspector.setDeepInspectionCandidates(Set.of(ClassA.class, ClassB.class));

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.string = "classA test string";
        classA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;

        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        classB.string = "classB test string";
        classB.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.TEN;
        classB.classA = classA;

        classA.classB = classB;

        assertThat(fieldInspector.isFullyInitialized(classA)).isTrue();

        classA.string = null;
        
        assertThat(fieldInspector.isFullyInitialized(classB)).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testDoHaveEqualFields_withoutDeepInspection() {
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.string = "classA test string";
        classA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
        classA.classB = classB;

        ClassB anotherClassB = new ClassB();

        ClassA anotherClassA = new ClassA();
        anotherClassA.string = "classA test string";
        anotherClassA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
        anotherClassA.classB = anotherClassB;

        assertThat(fieldInspector.doHaveEqualFields(classA, anotherClassA)).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testDoHaveEqualFields_withoutDeepInspection_comparesBigDecimalsIgnoringScaleByDefault() {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE.setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        ClassA anotherClassA = new ClassA();
        anotherClassA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        assertThat(fieldInspector.doHaveEqualFields(classA, anotherClassA)).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void testDoHaveEqualFields_withoutDeepInspection_withDefaultOverridden_comparesBigDecimalsWithScale() {
        fieldInspector.setClassesWithCustomEqualityChecks(Collections.emptyMap());

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE.setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        ClassA anotherClassA = new ClassA();
        anotherClassA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        assertThat(fieldInspector.doHaveEqualFields(classA, anotherClassA)).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testDoHaveEqualFields_withDeepInspection_withEqualFields() {
        fieldInspector.setDeepInspectionCandidates(Set.of(ClassB.class));

        ClassB classB = new ClassB();

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.string = "classA test string";
        classA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
        classA.classB = classB;

        ClassB anotherClassB = new ClassB();

        ClassA anotherClassA = new ClassA();
        anotherClassA.string = "classA test string";
        anotherClassA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
        anotherClassA.classB = anotherClassB;

        assertThat(fieldInspector.doHaveEqualFields(classA, anotherClassA)).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void testDoHaveEqualFields_withDeepInspection_withUnequalFields() {
        fieldInspector.setDeepInspectionCandidates(Set.of(ClassB.class));

        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        classB.string = "classB test string";

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.string = "classA test string";
        classA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
        classA.classB = classB;

        ClassB anotherClassB = new ClassB();
        anotherClassB.string = "another classB test string";

        ClassA anotherClassA = new ClassA();
        anotherClassA.string = "classA test string";
        anotherClassA.bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
        anotherClassA.classB = anotherClassB;

        assertThat(fieldInspector.doHaveEqualFields(classA, anotherClassA)).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void testDoHaveEqualFields_withDeepInspection_withEqualFields_cyclicDependenciesResolved() {
        fieldInspector.setDeepInspectionCandidates(Set.of(ClassB.class));

        ClassB classB = new ClassB();

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.classB = classB;

        ClassA anotherClassA = new ClassA();
        anotherClassA.classB = classB;

        classB.classA = classA;

        assertThat(fieldInspector.doHaveEqualFields(classA, anotherClassA)).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void testDoHaveEqualFields_withDeepInspection_withEqualFields_afterMethodInvocation_cacheInvalidated() {
        fieldInspector.setDeepInspectionCandidates(Set.of(ClassA.class, ClassB.class));

        ClassB classB = new ClassB();

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.classB = classB;

        classB.classA = classA;

        ClassB anotherClassB = new ClassB();

        ClassA anotherClassA = new ClassA();
        anotherClassA.classB = anotherClassB;

        anotherClassB.classA = anotherClassA;

        assertThat(fieldInspector.doHaveEqualFields(classA, anotherClassA)).isTrue();

        classB.string = "test string";

        assertThat(fieldInspector.doHaveEqualFields(classA, anotherClassA)).isFalse();
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration") // to suppress "field never accessed"
    private static class ClassA {
        private String string;
        private BigDecimal bigDecimal;
        private ClassB classB;
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration") // to suppress "field never accessed"
    private static class ClassB {
        private String string;
        private BigDecimal bigDecimal;
        private ClassA classA;
    }
}
```

```java
package by.afinny.credit.testUtil.fieldInspector;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;

public interface FieldInspector {
    <T> boolean doHaveEqualFields(T firstObject, T secondObject);

    void setDeepInspectionCandidates(Set<Class<?>> deepInspectionCandidates);

    void setClassesWithCustomEqualityChecks(Map<Class<?>, BiPredicate<Object, Object>> classesWithCustomEqualityChecks);

    <T> boolean isFullyInitialized(T generatedObject);
}
```

```java
package by.afinny.credit.testUtil.fieldInspector;

import by.afinny.credit.util.BigDecimalUtils;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class BasicFieldInspector implements FieldInspector {
    private final Set<Class<?>> deepInspectionCandidates;
    private final Map<Class<?>, BiPredicate<Object, Object>> classesWithCustomEqualityChecks;
    private final Set<Object> inspectedObjects = new HashSet<>();
    private final Map<Object, Object> comparedPairs = new HashMap<>();

    public BasicFieldInspector() {
        this.deepInspectionCandidates = new HashSet<>();
        this.classesWithCustomEqualityChecks = new HashMap<>();
        classesWithCustomEqualityChecks.put(BigDecimal.class,
                (bd1, bd2) -> BigDecimalUtils.areEqual((BigDecimal) bd1, (BigDecimal) bd2));
    }

    public BasicFieldInspector(Set<Class<?>> deepInspectionCandidates) {
        this.deepInspectionCandidates = deepInspectionCandidates;
        this.classesWithCustomEqualityChecks = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDeepInspectionCandidates(Set<Class<?>> deepInspectionCandidates) {
        this.deepInspectionCandidates.clear();
        this.deepInspectionCandidates.addAll(deepInspectionCandidates);
    }

    @Override
    public void setClassesWithCustomEqualityChecks(Map<Class<?>, BiPredicate<Object, Object>> classesWithCustomEqualityChecks) {
        this.classesWithCustomEqualityChecks.clear();
        this.classesWithCustomEqualityChecks.putAll(classesWithCustomEqualityChecks);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> boolean isFullyInitialized(T object) {
        boolean isFullyInitialized = isFullyInitialized0(object);
        inspectedObjects.clear();
        return isFullyInitialized;
    }

    private <T> boolean isFullyInitialized0(T object) {
        Set<Object> memorizedObjects = new HashSet<>();
        for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object fieldValue = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, object);
            if (fieldValue == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (shouldBeDeepInspected(fieldValue)) {
                memorizedObjects.add(fieldValue);
            }
        }
        inspectedObjects.add(object);
        for (Object memorizedObject : memorizedObjects) {
            if (!isFullyInitialized0(memorizedObject)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean shouldBeDeepInspected(Object fieldValue) {
        return fieldValue != null &&
                !inspectedObjects.contains(fieldValue) &&
                deepInspectionCandidates.contains(fieldValue.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public <T> boolean doHaveEqualFields(T firstObject, T secondObject) {
        boolean doHaveEqualFields = doHaveEqualFields0(firstObject, secondObject);
        comparedPairs.clear();
        return doHaveEqualFields;
    }

    private <T> boolean doHaveEqualFields0(T firstObject, T secondObject) {
        Map<Object, Object> memorizedPairs = new HashMap<>();
        for (Field field : firstObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object firstObjectFieldValue = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, firstObject);
            Object secondObjectFieldValue = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, secondObject);
            if (shouldBeCompared(firstObjectFieldValue, secondObjectFieldValue)) {
                if (deepInspectionCandidates.contains(field.getType())) {
                    memorizedPairs.put(firstObjectFieldValue, secondObjectFieldValue);
                } else {
                    if (areNotEqual(firstObjectFieldValue, secondObjectFieldValue)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        comparedPairs.put(firstObject, secondObject);
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> pair : memorizedPairs.entrySet()) {
            if (!(doHaveEqualFields0(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue()))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean shouldBeCompared(Object fieldValue, Object anotherFieldValue) {
        return !comparedPairs.containsKey(fieldValue) ||
                !comparedPairs.get(fieldValue).equals(anotherFieldValue);
    }

    private <T> boolean areNotEqual(T firstObjectFieldValue, T secondObjectFieldValue) {
        if (firstObjectFieldValue == null && secondObjectFieldValue == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Class<?> type = Stream.of(firstObjectFieldValue, secondObjectFieldValue)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .findAny()
                .get()
                .getClass();
        if (classesWithCustomEqualityChecks.containsKey(type)) {
            BiPredicate<Object, Object> customEquals = classesWithCustomEqualityChecks.get(type);
            return !customEquals.test(firstObjectFieldValue, secondObjectFieldValue);
        } else {
            return !Objects.equals(firstObjectFieldValue, secondObjectFieldValue);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package by.afinny.credit.util;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class BigDecimalUtils {
    private BigDecimalUtils() {
    }

    /**
     * Compares two instances of {@code BigDecimal} ignoring scale. If both instances
     * are {@code null}, returns true
     *
     * @return {@code true} if two decimals are equal, {@code false} otherwise
     */
    public static boolean areEqual(BigDecimal firstDecimal, BigDecimal secondDecimal) {
        return (firstDecimal == null) ?
                (secondDecimal == null) :
                (secondDecimal != null) && (firstDecimal.compareTo(secondDecimal) == 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abstract method and fied naming with the lack of documentation makes the review quite difficult. Naming should describe their purpose accurately.

My first guess about "deep inspection candidates" was that the name refers to objects that are to be inspected. I had to look at the type of the field to realize that it's the types that are to be inspected. That field should be renamed to `typesToInspect`. "Deep inspection candidate" feels like there was a subconcious desire to create fancy terminology. I've done it too and it's something a programmer should be aware of. Don't try to create unnecessary new names for things that can have mundane and easy to understand names. :)

`isFullyInitializded` should be renamed to `allFieldsAreNonNull` or `areAllFieldsNonNull` because that's literally what the method does. Also, what "full initialization" means depends on the purpose of the class being inspected so in general you shouldn't automatically assume that a field being null makes an *object* uninitialized.

"Memorized objects" doesn't tell why the objects are being memorized (memorizing is not a known computing term). A better term could be "referencesToBeInspected". You should extract the code that finds the references from an object into a separate method named `private Set<Object> findReferencesToInspect(Object source)`.

The set of already inspected objects doesn't need to be a class member. You can instantiate that set in `isFullyInitialized` and pass it as a parameter to the private recursive function. Keeping state in a class member makes the class thread unsafe and means you can't share an instance of your utility for example when running tests in parallel. And you don't have to worry about clearing the set (or worry about the memory leak that happens when the inspection fails with an exception and the set doesn't get cleared).

The equality check and the null check should be split into separate classes (single responsibility principle). Separating these features makes the code easier to follow as the reader doesn't have to guess whichs fields and methods are related to which feature. Also you won't then be starting *yet another big mess of utility methods*. Those classes are a menace for maintenance.

Names should not contain negations such as `areNotEqual`. Those lead to statements with duble negatives like `if (! areNotEqual(...))` which are hard for humans to follow. So make it `areEqual` and `if (! areEqual(...))`.

Comment: Thank you! I was just about to edit and add documentation. **1.** `isFullyInitailized()` is preferable to `allFieldsAreNonNull()` since "full initialization" is implemented differently by *deep `FieldInspectors`* (those that recursively inspect field values of field values of *deep inspection type* – `BasicFieldInspector` is an example of a deep `FieldInspector`). **2.** Is *memoized* better? The objects are *memoized* so that my `FieldInspector` doesn't jump to recursive inspection right away and get `StackOverflowError` in case of cyclic dependencies

Comment: **3.** Isn't it common (and acceptable) for utility methods to contain methods that do different things (think all the Apache Commons utilities)? **4.** If all invocations of a boolean method are inverted, IntelliJ throws a warning so I figured I should avoid that

Comment: **5.** Also, are you sure about `inspectedObjects` and `comparedFields`? If I make them local variables, I need to pass them, including to methods related to equality that already take two arguments, like `shouldBeCompared()` which becomes `shouldBeCompared(Object fieldValue, Object anotherFieldValue, Map<Object, Object> comparedPairs)`

Comment: I'd actually prefer separate `areEqual` and `areNotEqual` methods to be able to use the proper form in my code. If someone uses `!areNotEqual` without need it's IMHO not the fault of the library.

Comment: Regarding 3: That is true for static methods but your use case is different since you have state within your inspector. An instance initialized for inspection may not be valid for use as a comparator. 5: Reducing the risk from not being thread safe and from memory leaks is far greater than an extra parameter in a private method.

Comment: @Marvin But then you have introduced redundant methods and the cost for documenting, maintaining and testing them. Do you provide such a method for all boolean returning methods, doubling the size of the API, or just for select methods? And if latter, is the inconsistency clear to the API user or do they wonder why only some methods receive these counterparts? The standard Java APIs don't provide these either so the users are probably used to not needing them.

Comment: I'm working with Kotlin that e.g. has `isBlank` and `isNotBlank` functions for a string, and I a) like the ability to avoid easy-to-overlook `!"foo".isBlank()` code and b) so far haven't been confused that not every boolean function on strings is available in both formats. Of course it's a trade-off but I do not agree with your statement in its general form.

Comment: @Marvin Ah, well this is Java and Kotlin is just unnecessary syntactic excess built on the JVM only because Google needed an alternative language to safeguard themselves from further law suits from Sun Microsystems. :) At least that's my Completely Honest Opinion.